# Apache Ignite Data Region behaviour

Tags: ignite

I am implementing the Data Region in apache ignite cluster with 4 nodes and each node having 20GB RAM. I have some doubts with data region configuration.

1. Does DataRegionConfiguration maxMemory configured based upon all nodes memory?(Means, If we configure the 10GB in maxMemory then will it create the single data region for all the nodes and remaining memory will be 4*20-10 = 70GB)
2. can we bind the node based upon data region configuration?(Means, Cache which is associated with particular region should be stored the cache data on particular node instead of partitioned on all the nodes)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

1. `DataRegionConfiguration` is local for each node. If you set max size to 10Gb, it means 10Gb for single node. If you start two nodes with same config, you get 20Gb total size.
2. You can configure any data region for one or more nodes, in other words have separate configuration for each node. Then you can setup [node filter](https://ignite.apache.org/releases/latest/javadoc/org/apache/ignite/configuration/CacheConfiguration.html#setNodeFilter-org.apache.ignite.lang.IgnitePredicate-) that will define set of nodes that could store your cache. To configure it from XML, you can use [AttributeNodeFilter](https://static.javadoc.io/org.apache.ignite/ignite-core/2.5.0/org/apache/ignite/util/AttributeNodeFilter.html) and set your attributes for proper nodes in [IgniteConfiguration](https://ignite.apache.org/releases/latest/javadoc/org/apache/ignite/configuration/IgniteConfiguration.html#setUserAttributes-java.util.Map-). This way you can setup data regions for required nodes and settle caches on that nodes using node filter + node attributes.

Comment: Hi Mitya, I follow the steps 2nd but getting following error whenever we run the 2nd node.
org.apache.ignite.IgniteCheckedException: Requested DataRegion is not configured: Server1DataNode
Note: I have created the "Server1DataNode" data region on node-1. On node-2, data region name is "Server2DataNode"

Comment: I think the issue lays in fact that cache started on all nodes, but keeps data only on that, which satisfy node filter. To overcome it, you may create fake data region of the same name on nodes, that should not keep data, with minimal size (10Mbytes). Or use default data region that exists on all nodes.